# How to call WCF Service using JMeter?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, jmeter

I have to test my WCF Service using JMeter.

Is it possible to call particular api method from WCF Service using JMeter?

If we can is there any demo available? I also need to pass parameters to method.

I already checked following resources.

[Using JMeter to load test WCF POST REST Service](https://blog.gisspan.com/2015/10/using-jmeter-to-load-test-wcf-post-rest.html)
In this example they are not specifying how to call particular Save method.

**I am having soap WCF service. How can i call particular API and pass parameters?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of SOAP you can call this or that method using [SOAPAction](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/post/unraveling_the_mystery_of_soap.html) header. This header value along with [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header can be specified via JMeter's [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager)

See [Building a SOAP WebService Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html) JMeter User Manual chapter for more information.

Comment: but how can i access WCF API Method?? it can be accessed using URL? In above example they shows accessing standard web service...